# Odoo 10: Input field next to a boolen field

Tags: xml, input, view, boolean, odoo

I want to create a view like below in a notebook where input fields are next to boolean fields :

[image]

I tried below code but it didnt work :

```
<notebook colspan="4">
    <page name="HR Team" string="HR Team" >
         <group string="All Employees">
                 <table>
                     <td><field name="onBoardingMail" attrs="{'readonly':True}" /></td>
                      <td><field name="onBoardingMail_comment"  /></td> 
                </table>
        </group>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

What is the right way to achieve that view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below view should work, and the input field can be read-only when the checkbox is False.

```
<notebook colspan="4">
    <page name="HR Team" string="HR Team">
        <group string="All Employees">
            <label string="onBoarding Email" for="onBoardingMail_comment" class="oe_inline"/>
            <div>
                <field name="onBoardingMail" nolabel="1" class="oe_inline"/>
                <field name="onBoardingMail_comment" placeholder="This is a Comment" nolabel="1" class="oe_inline" attrs="{'readonly':[('onBoardingMail','=',False)]}"/>
            </div>
        </group>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

When checkbox enabled:

[image]

When checkbox disabled:

[image]